# pymongo insert_one not writing but returning objectid

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

Running CentOS7, python 3.6.6, mongo 4.0.2, r/w access to database unrestricted, no users have been setup.

I'm trying to scrape reddit comments and add them to a database, the code is as follows --

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
client = MongoClient()

db = client.reddit_comments
posts = db.posts
post_data = {
    'postid': submission.id,
    'created': submission.created,
    'title': submission.title
}
print(post_data)
result = db.reddit_comments.insert_one(post_data)
print('One post: {0}'.format(result.inserted_id))
```

The printed output, my post data and result, is as follows --

```
{'postid': '7p1x7e', 'created': 1515722415.0, 'title': 'comment stuff'}
One post: 5b95bf479dc6d638808ab230
{'postid': '7d5klp', 'created': 1515512050.0, 'title': 'comment stuff'}
One post: 5b95bf479dc6d638808ab231
{'postid': '7sds10', 'created': 1516345119.0, 'title': 'comment stuff'}
One post: 5b95bf479dc6d638808ab232
```

Copying the post_data and manually inserting it into my db works, but this script doesn't seem to insert it. Am I missing something here?

Comment: Do you mean to insert in the `reddit_comments` collection or the `posts` collection of the database? Can you share how you are manually inserting into your db?

Answer (score 0):

If you are running into an issue like this it's probably that you are inserting into your mongodb instance, just not where you think you are. Try seeing if you've inadvertently created a new collection, database, field, etc...

In my case I had inadvertently created a new collection and was successfully adding records to the wrong collection, it wasn't until I refreshed my database GUI and saw the new collection that this clicked for me.